# How to interpretate rcrimeanalysis

Tags: r

I know english till certain level and also tryied translator, but it didn't was clear, then, I need some help to interpretate what is a Net Difference Raster. I'm exploring rcrimeanalysis package, and here's my code.

```
library(rcrimeanalysis)
library(tidyverse)

data("crimes")

narcotics <- subset(crimes, crimes$primary_type == "NARCOTICS")

interval <- kde_int_comp(narcotics,
                         start1="1/1/2017", 
                         end1="3/1/2017", 
                         start2="1/1/2018", 
                         end2="3/1/2018")

interval

crime_samp <- head(crimes, n = 1000)
out <- near_repeat_analysis(data = crime_samp, 
                            tz = "America/Chicago",
                            epsg = "32616")
near_repeat_eval(data = crime_samp, 
                 tz = "America/Chicago",
                 epsg = "32616")
```

kde_int_comp() plots a Difference Network Raster, but how do I read this map, the more blue, more crime intesified in that area? And there are regions that crime didn't happenned after the year passed and the net difference plots does not marks it. I'm confused.
[image: Net Difference Raster]

And for last, I couldn't also understand the return of near_repeat_eval(). It gives Distance and Time, and it looks like parameters to use somewhere else.

Comment: near_repeat_eval() gives parameters to fill near_repeat_analysis()

Comment: This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you need help interpreting data on plots, you could ask for help at [stats.se] where data visualization is on topic. But if the package documentation is insufficient to help you understand the plot, then you may want to contact the package author https://github.com/JSSpaulding/rcrimeanalysis